# Arrange HTML elements in overlapping rows

Tags: html, image, text, layout

[image: img of html code]Desired layout:

[image]

I want to create the layout of html elements arranged in overlapping rows as in the diagram.

The text boxes are of the form `input type='text' size='10' /`.

I've tried giving elements a particular size but the text boxes are not an integer number of pixels in size so the arrangement soon goes out of step.

I've tried arrange them with table type `<div>` elements but failed to find an arrangement that worked.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: you can use absolute positioning, and absolute sizing: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp though this is very restirctive, specifically for a responsive page - i.e. for mobile etc.  would be useful if you could add code to your question - show what you have tried etc.

Comment: Thanks for your info on the position property, I look forward to trying it. I failed to get my html into the post (new user). Will try again later.

Comment: Can you please provide more code. this is very limited for us to help you out

Comment: The solution provided by the unnamed developer involving absolute positioning works perfectly. Thanks.